# chrome extension - create custom devtools network panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to add a panel to chrome DevTools to have some informations about network traffic. I already have some code inside a `background.js` script of my extension, how I can reuse it for te panel?

Comment: To reuse the code, extract it to a separate js file and use it in both places. Depending on what it does, [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) may be a better choice.

Comment: @wOxxOm So I need also to create html page for the devtool panel? I just need the code in one place, at the moment I'm inspecting traffic using `webRequest` but since I need more accuracy, I want to switch to network devtool api. I need to get the response body content of certain requests

Comment: It's be best to start with the demo extensions and read the documentation.

Comment: I've added a panel to the console, works fine, but if I use `console.log()` I don't see anything in the console where the panel is loaded, where are logged the informations?

Comment: Right-click the panel and click "inspect" to open devtools for devtools and for your panel.

Comment: I'm only loading the js code into the panel html file but ok, I will try. Thank you